# Laravel: Jquery on click function issue

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am trying to `alert` something but on click function is `running only once` on the first button. but I have `buttons on many rows`.

I am fetching Data through Laravel from Database in a table. Only one button runs a function, then nothing happens with other buttons.

**Jquery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e)  {
    $('#restore-data').on('click', function(e) {
    var val = $("#thisr").attr('value');
    alert(val);

    });
});
```

**View:**

```html
<table id="recover-table" class="table" >
    <thead>
    <tr class="bg-info">
        <th>Teacher Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    @foreach($trashs as $trash)

    <tr id="thisr" value="{{$trash->id}}">
    <td class="text-nowrap ">{{$trash->efirst}} {{$trash->esecond}}</td>

    <td class="text-nowrap ">{{$trash->deleted_at}}</td>

    <td class="text-nowrap "><button type="submit"  class="" name="id" 
    value="{{$trash->id}}" id="restore-data">Delete</button></td>

    </tr>

    @endforeach </tbody></table>
```

Right now even alert is not working, but I want to achieve Refresh table after a record is deleted from Table.

**Update:** Now Alert is working fine, but when I delete a record by pressing a button, only one row is deleting. the function runs once.

**Complete Js:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e)  {

    $('#restore-data').on('click', function(e) {

    let teacher_id=$(this).attr('value');
    console.log('Restore button clicked!')
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax(
    {
      url: "/teachers/recover/" + $('#restore-data').attr("value"),
      type: 'GET', // Just delete Latter Capital Is Working Fine
      headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
      data: teacher_id,

     success: function (data) {
     console.log(data.msg);
     console.log(teacher_id);

     if(data.msg){
         $('#thisr').remove();
         $('#response').empty();
         $(".toast").toast('show');
         $('#response').append(data.msg);
      }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
    console.log("Error Restoring Record");
    //console.log(xhr.responseText);
    },
   });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use class 'restore-data'

```
$(document).ready(function(e)  {
    $(document).on('click', '.restore-data', function(e) {
        var val = $('#thisr').val();
        alert(val);
    });
});
```

As id should be unique for each element.

You can try something like

```
@foreach($trashs as $trash)

<tr>
<td class="text-nowrap ">{{$trash->efirst}} {{$trash->esecond}}</td>

<td class="text-nowrap ">{{$trash->deleted_at}}</td>

<td class="text-nowrap ">
    <button type="button" data-trash-id="{{$trash->id}}" class="restore-data">Delete</button>
</td>

</tr>

@endforeach
```

and JS as

```
$(document).on('click', '.restore-data', function(e) {
    var trash_id = $(this).attr('data-trash-id');
    alert(trash_id);
});
```

Comment: please check my edited answer last portion. if you can help thanks.

Comment: I have updated the answer, You need to use unique ids, you can use laravel blade loop variables

Comment: deleting only first row.

Comment: Please let me know if the alert shows the correct value?

Comment: As you can add attr to the button there is no need for them on tr. I have added data-trash-id attribute. If you need to remove parent tr tag then you can use `$(this).parent('tr').remove();` or `$(this).closest('tr').remove();`

Answer (score 3):

Change this line.

```
var val = $("#thisr").attr('value');
```

to (since you have value attribute in button):

```
var val = $(this).attr('value');
```

or (since you have value attribute td):

```
var val = $(this).parent('tr#thisr').attr('value')
```

To remove a row.

```
$('#restore-data').on('click', function(e) {

 var _this = $(this);
 ...

if(data.msg){
  _this.parent('tr#thisr').remove();
....
```

Also change button type to button.

```
<button type="button"  class="" name="id" 
    value="{{$trash->id}}" id="restore-data">Delete</button></td>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working for alert, but how can i reload only table after alert.

Comment: please check my edited answer last portion. if you can help  thanks.

Comment: still running only once. please check

Comment: added _this.parent('tr#thisr').remove(); but still only one row removed, not second. :(

Comment: i added alert(1) in start and that too runs once.

Comment: i clicked on second row after reload and nothing happens, but on first row it's deleting row, maybe id issue?

Comment: @Fayakon yeah or better check your controller

Comment: i really appreciate your efforts. at least alert should work on each button, but it's not when i add delete functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You gave same `id` to all button and id must be unique of particular button so you can define unique id with key of array and pass it to Function

```php
@foreach($trashs as $key=>$trash)

<tr id="thisr{{$key}}">
    <td class="text-nowrap ">{{$trash->efirst}} {{$trash->esecond}}</td>
    <td class="text-nowrap ">{{$trash->deleted_at}}</td>
    <td class="text-nowrap ">
        <button type="button"  class="" name="id" value="{{$trash->id}}" id="restore-data{{$key}}" onclick="restoreData({{$key}})">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

```
function restoreData(key){
    var val = $("#restore-data"+key).attr('value');
    alert(val);
    // you can use either
    $("#restore-data"+key).closest('tr').remove();
    // OR
    $('#thisr'+key).remove();
}
```

Comment: please check my edited answer last portion. if you can help thanks.

Comment: Thankyou so much can you modify code to delete rows?

Comment: try last line of the function i modified to delete row

Comment: i am using $('#restore-data').on('click', function(e), how can i pass key in it instead of using onclick.

Comment: you just check foreach in my code i used function....if you want to test just copy paste foreach and js function

Comment: Check this line `<button type="button"  class="" name="id" value="{{$trash->id}}" id="restore-data{{$key}}" onclick="restoreData({{$key}})">Delete</button>`

Comment: and also see in foreach i added `$key`

Comment: i modified `<tr>` tag also

Comment: i get restoreData not defined is that's why i want to go without onclick in tag.